# Paragraph text CSS affected by child element?

Tags: html, css

Can someone please explain to me why the `<div>` somehow affects the CSS of the `<p>` that contains it?

```
<style>p { font-family: Arial }</style>
...
<p>some text</p>
<p><div></div>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
```

In this example, the font in the second paragraph will change to the browser's default font.  Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding a div in your paragraph tag you are breaking your HTML. You will end up with something similar to:

```
<p>some text</p>
<p></p><div></div>some text<p></p>
<p>some text</p>
```

And so your font is not applied.

Paragraph tags may only contain [phrasing-content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content). If you need to wrap text within your paragraph tags, consider using the `<span>` tag.

Comment: Thank-you for the clear answer.  I should probably know this by now :)

Answer (score 1):

@Adrift is right, you can't nest block-level elements inside text tags. That's like saying 'there's an article inside this sentence', rather than 'there's a sentence inside this article'. This is because block level elements force a line break before and after themselves.

If you aren't using a CSS reset method, like a reset stylesheet or [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), the strange styling could be caused by the browser's user agent stylesheet (the default styles browsers use in the absence of anything else).